# Próximo registro. PHP + Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, while

Sou iniciante em programação e gostaria de saber como eu faria meu **$id = 1**, virar 2, 3 e assim sucessivamente. O código no final, significa que ele precisa comparar aquele valor e só depois ocorrer um `$id++`. Sei que preciso inserir dentro de um `while`, mas não estou sabendo colocar.

Seria assim, cada $row seria uma carta, eu coloquei 9 apenas para teste. É um jogo no estilo super trunfo, ou seja, no início aparecerá apenas 1 (uma carta), e a pessoa selecionará seu atributo, isso é feito através do `$_POST("Submit")`. Após a pessoa clicar, esse atributo comparará com outro atributo, onde coloquei aquele (`$select > 10`) apenas como exemplo. Logo em seguida, o `$id=1` precisa virar 2, para o jogo continuar até chegar `$id=9`.

Sim! É um jogo de cartas, tipo Super Trunfo sabe?! A regra é muito simples, pois o jogador mesmo ganhando ou perdendo, a carta dele tem que mudar. O que acontece é que cada carta, eu inseri ali pelo `$row[1]`. Então depois de fazer esse comparação, que é somente para teste (Pois comparar com outra carta eu já consegui aplicar), irá para a próxima carta, que seria `$row[2]`. E isso ocorre até chegar ao `$row[9]`.

Deu para entender melhor?

Eu não quero jogar todo select de uma vez na tela, e sim aparecer apenas um, e logo em seguida, após essa comparação feita por botão("Submit"), aparecer o `$id=2` e assim por diante.

Resumindo, o que eu preciso é que inicie com 1, e assim que fizer a comparação e clicar no botão, a próxima "tela" seja o 2.

```
include ("connect.php");  //Conexão Banco

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM card");

$id = 1;

$row[1] = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$row[2] = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$row[3] = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$row[4] = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$row[5] = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$row[6] = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$row[7] = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$row[8] = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$row[9] = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$pic = $row[$id]["Photo"]; 
$rk = $row[$id]["Ranking"]; 
$tt = $row[$id]["Tittles"];
$st = $row[$id]["Started"];
$ya = $row[$id]["Years Active"];
if (isset($_POST["Submit"])){       
    if (!empty($_POST["game"])){ 
        foreach ($_POST ["game"] as $selected) { 
            if ($selected > 10) { 
                echo "win"; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Você pode fazer um for().. teria um link que irá clicar para poder ir a proxima pagina?

Comment: Não estou conseguindo entender onde quer chegar.... Consegue explicar melhor a situação?

Comment: Explique melhor qual é o objetivo desse código ... parece algum tipo de jogo de cartas ... qual é a regra? o jogador recebe 9 cartas e o que acontece?

Comment: Lembrando que funções mysql_* estão obsoletas desde o PHP 5.5  e serão removidas do PHP em breve. Prefira usar MySQLi ou PDO. Veja mais aqui: http://www.ultimatephp.com.br/php-por-que-nao-utilizar-funcoes-mysql

Comment: @Felipe juntei texto da resposta que tinhas colocado. Apaguei porque não era uma resposta. Podes [edit] a pergunta e ver se o texto está certo? Assim vamos poder ajudar melhor.

Comment: Sem problemas!!!

Answer (score 3):

Se eu entendi bem, vc precisa buscar vários ids diferentes em uma tabela, para isso, vc precisa de um laço de repetição (não precisa ser necessáriamente um while), com um for, por exemplo, seria mais ou menos assim:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=9; $i++){
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM card WHERE id=".$id);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

  //aqui vai toda a sua logica com o $row
}
```

**Mas cuidado**, esse é um exemplo super simples e com falhas de segurança. Só fiz para vc entender a lógica necessária. Recomendo vc dar uma lida na documentação do php que diz como fazer consultas no banco da melhor forma.
Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 2):

Como já foi informado na citação anterior, essas não são as melhores formas de fazer isso.
O exemplo acima faz o que pediu, além dele, como você comentou sobre o while:

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 10){
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM card WHERE id=".$id.");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

  //aqui vai toda a sua logica com o $row
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Atente-se que um *loop* de 1 a 10 usando `SELECT * FROM card WHERE id = {$id++}` não garante que retorne 10 registros! Se entre o limite de 10 houver 1 registro deletado, então você terá registos inferiores ao que deseja.

<sub>Como exemplo vou usar uma quantia menor para não alongar a resposta. **Minha sugestão se baseia no uso de apena 2 consultas com os *IDs* disponíveis sequencialmente.**:</sub>

---

Dessa forma você obtém N registros com *IDs* sequenciais, perceba que o *ID-3* e o *ID-6* foram removidos e mesmo assim retorna 5 *IDs*, no caso da query dentro de um laço seriam retornados 3 registros:

**`SQL:`**`select id from tabela limit 5`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
            [id] => 1

    [1] => Array
            [id] => 2

    [2] => Array
            [id] => 4

    [3] => Array
            [id] => 5

    [4] => Array
            [id] => 7

)
```

Usando um `foreach` para criar uma lista dos *IDs* encontrados:

```
foreach( mysql_fetch_array($sql) as $rows )
{
    $ids[] = $rows['id'];
}
```

Agora usando `implode` para montar uma query com `where id in` para retornar rodos os registros com os *IDs* que foram encontrados acima: `where id in( 1,2,4,5,7)`

**`SQL:`**`select id , nome from tabela where id in( ' . implode( ',' , $ids ) . ' )`

---

### Resultado final

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [nome] => nome 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [nome] => nome 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [nome] => nome 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [nome] => nome 5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [nome] => nome 7
        )
)
```

Comment: Rapaz, ainda não consegui inserir o código! Foi modificada a pergunta! Veja se consegue entender melhor? Desde já, Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, tente desta forma:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM card");
while($dado = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   $id = $dado['id'];
}
```

Desta forma a variável `$id`, vai receber todos os ID's da tabela enquanto houver dados